# JOIN with UNNEST() in PostgreSQL, to access a trigger's OF column names

Tags: postgresql, unnest

I'd like to select the name(s) of the `OF` column(s) of a trigger (in order if possible).

When I select the trigger's array of column *numbers*, it works fine.

```
D:\pdgm\trunk\psc2>psql -h nemo
Password for user ddevienne:
psql (12.1, server 12.0)
...
ddevienne=> SELECT t.tgattr
ddevienne->   FROM pg_namespace n
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_trigger   t ON t.tgrelid      = c.oid
ddevienne->  WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
ddevienne->    AND c.relname = 'ut_trigger'
ddevienne->    AND t.tgname = 'keepnamehistorytrigger'
ddevienne-> ;
 tgattr
--------
 2 3
(1 row)
```

But when I try to `UNNEST` that array to join it with `pg_attributes`, if fails.
It's a *correlated-join*, trying to expand the array into its *rows*, knowing that
the previous joins select a single row, for the trigger in question.

```
ddevienne=> SELECT trig_cols.col_num
ddevienne->   FROM pg_namespace n
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_trigger   t ON t.tgrelid      = c.oid
ddevienne->   JOIN UNNEST(t.tgattr) as trig_cols(col_num)
ddevienne->  WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
ddevienne->    AND c.relname = 'ut_trigger'
ddevienne->    AND t.tgname = 'keepnamehistorytrigger'
ddevienne-> ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 6:  WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
         ^
ddevienne=>
```

I'm expecting 2 rows, of values `2` and `3`, that I could then
`JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = trig_cols.col_num```.

What am I missing? Thanks, --DD

## Update

Thank you. I was missing the `ON true` (or `CROSS JOIN`).
Here's the final version, that preserves order using `WITH ORDINALITY`.

```
ddevienne=> SELECT a.attname
ddevienne->   FROM pg_namespace n
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_trigger   t ON t.tgrelid      = c.oid
ddevienne->   JOIN UNNEST(t.tgattr) WITH ORDINALITY as trig_cols(col_num, col_idx) ON true
ddevienne->   JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid     = c.oid
ddevienne->                      AND a.attnum       = trig_cols.col_num
ddevienne->   WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
ddevienne->    AND t.tgname = 'keepnamehistorytrigger'
ddevienne->    AND c.relname = 'ut_trigger'
ddevienne->  ORDER BY trig_cols.col_idx
ddevienne-> ;
 attname
----------
 name
 Alt_Name
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JOIN` needs a join condition:

```
SELECT trig_cols.col_num
  FROM pg_namespace n
  JOIN pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
  JOIN pg_trigger   t ON t.tgrelid      = c.oid
  JOIN UNNEST(t.tgattr) as trig_cols(col_num) ON true --<< here
 WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
   AND c.relname = 'ut_trigger'
   AND t.tgname = 'keepnamehistorytrigger'
```

Alternatively use

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.tgattr) as trig_cols(col_num)
```